# Python website scraping python and parsing data

Tags: python, unicode

I'm a Python beginner and I am having trouble scraping a webpage and displaying specific text from the page.

I know my problem lies within the encoding as I have been reading [unicode type](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) and have seen other newbies having the exact same issue.

For example lets say I wanted to scrape www.amazon.com this is the code I have

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, 'http://www.amazon.com')
curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
curl.perform()

result = buf.getvalue()
result = unicode(result, "ascii", errors="ignore")
buf.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(result)
print soup.get_text()
```

This returns the amazon web page to the result variable.
But I get the annoying error when trying to use the beautifulsoup get_text() method:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 25790: ordinal not in range(128)

How do I ensure / decode the entire results of the contents returned within my curl request.

Comment: How this is python 3 and you have `print` as keyword?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use requests instead, its simpler and cleaner and AFAIK avoids the encoding issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://www.amazon.com')

bsoup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
print(bsoup.get_text())
```

There are reasons to use CURL, but requests is simpler and easier in most cases and your situation doesn't look like an exception based on what you describe.

EDIT: to resolve the unicode error, try explicitly encoding the string as utf-8 (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) SO question):

```
encoded = resp.text.encode('utf-8')
bsoup = BeautifulSoup(encoded)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the encoding error.
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 25921: ordinal not in range(128)`